# can't access any programs or files despite being connect over RDP

Tags: kubuntu, remote

I have Kubuntu 22.10 installed on another computer on my home network. It has KDE plasma 5.25.5 and is the only OS on that machine. I am now trying to set it up so that I can run it headless and access it via RDP with mRemoteNG from my main Windows computer. It is currently connected directly to my second monitor with a separate k/b and mouse, but once I get RDP running I intend to remove those. I have gotten it to the point that I can login and access the desktop and system settings over RDP with mRemoteNG or Windows remote desktop connection program, the problem is that I cannot open any other files or programs - they just don't show up. I feel like it's probably a permissions thing or something, but the account I'm logged into is an administrator account so quite frankly I'm stumped. Any advice tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:  When I physically log in to the machine instead of over the network, (and using the same user account), I have no problems at all.  All of the programs and files are visible and I'm able to do whatever I want.

Comment: You don't mention it in your question, but I assume that when you log in to the physical machine headed, as that same user, you can access the files?  If so, would you edit the question to make that clear?  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Done!  Thanks for taking time to look at this!